# How to set color for position '0' of ExpandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, background-color, expandablelistadapter

I have four activity classes, I need to implement four different colors for four activities, I have an ExpandableListAdapter like:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
String colors;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,String color) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.colors=color;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    CheckedTextView txtListChild = (CheckedTextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    txtListChild.setTypeface(TypeFaceConstant.getGibsonregular(_context));
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if(groupPosition==2){
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }else
        return 0;

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    CheckedTextView lblListHeader = (CheckedTextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(TypeFaceConstant.getGibsonregular(_context));

    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

And my activity class is like:

```
 public class OfficeScreenActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

LinearLayout office,roaster,food_service,hospitality;


ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
TextView lblListHeader,office_text;

ImageView play,logo,office_image;
LinearLayout ln;
Context context;
Bundle bundle;
ArrayList<Content> al;

HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_office_screen);


    play=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    logo=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_button);

    roaster=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.roaster_lay);
    food_service=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.food_lay);
    hospitality=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hosp_lay);

    office_image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.office_image);
    office_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.office_color);

    office_text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.office_text);
    office_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#57B7B2"));



    roaster.setOnClickListener(this);
    food_service.setOnClickListener(this);
    hospitality.setOnClickListener(this);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    logo.setOnClickListener(this);

    FragmentManager fm;
    IntroductionFragment fragment = new IntroductionFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String str="    office coffiee that will \n have everyone talking.";

    String str1="SOLA";
    String str2=" BEV OFFICE COFFEE SYSTEM SOLUTIONS";
    final String colors="#57B7B2";
    //bundle.putString("office",str);
    bundle.putString("sola", str1);
    bundle.putString("bev", str2);
    bundle.putString("office",str);
    bundle.putString("color", colors);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame1, fragment, "NewFragmentTag").commit(); 

    // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);


            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild,colors);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview Group click listener

            //expListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#57B7B2"));
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
                CheckedTextView lastClickedView;


                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {


                    if(groupPosition==0){


                        FragmentManager fm;
                                IntroductionFragment fragment = new IntroductionFragment();
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                String str="    office coffiee that will \n have everyone talking.";
                                String str1="SOLA";
                                String colors="#57B7B2";
                                String str2=" BEV OFFICE COFFEE SYSTEM SOLUTIONS";
                                bundle.putString("office",str);
                                bundle.putString("sola", str1);
                                bundle.putString("bev", str2);
                                bundle.putString("color", colors);
                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                    fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
                                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame1, fragment, "NewFragmentTag").commit(); 


                    }
                    else if(groupPosition==1){


                        FragmentManager fm;
                                KeyPointsFragment fragment = new KeyPointsFragment();

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            String token="office";
                                bundle.putString("office", token);
                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                    fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
                                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame1, fragment, "NewFragmentTag").commit(); 

                    }
                    else if(groupPosition==3){


                        FragmentManager fm;
                                PresentationsFragment fragment = new PresentationsFragment();
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                String str="PRESENTATIONS";
                                //String str1="SOLA";
                                String colors="#57B7B2";
                                //String str2=" BEV OFFICE COFFEE SYSTEM SOLUTIONS";
                                bundle.putString("present_title",str);
                                bundle.putString("cate_id", "1");
                                //bundle.putString("sola", str1);
                                //bundle.putString("bev", str2);
                                bundle.putString("color", colors);
                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                    fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
                                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame1, fragment, "NewFragmentTag").commit(); 


                    }


                    if(null!=lastClickedView){  
                           lastClickedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#232323"));
                      }
                      CheckedTextView txt3=(CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
                      if(!(groupPosition==2)){
                           txt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#57B7B2"));
                           //txt3.setTypeface(TypeFaceConstant.getGibsonBold(getApplicationContext()));
                        lastClickedView=txt3;
                      } 

                    if(groupPosition==2){
                     lblListHeader = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

                    lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B0AFAF"));
                    }


                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Listview Group expanded listener
            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Listview Group collasped listener
            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    if(groupPosition==2){
                    lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            // Listview on child click listener
            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
                CheckedTextView lastClickedView;
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(childPosition==0){


                          Intent mInHome1112 = new Intent(OfficeScreenActivity.this,BrewersActivity.class);
                          mInHome1112.putExtra("cate_id", "1");
                            OfficeScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mInHome1112);

                    }
                    else if(childPosition==1){

                          Intent mInHome1112 = new Intent(OfficeScreenActivity.this,CapsulesActivity.class);
                          mInHome1112.putExtra("cate_id", "1");
                          mInHome1112.putExtra("Avtivity", "Office");
                            OfficeScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mInHome1112);

                    }
                    if(null!=lastClickedView){  
                           lastClickedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#232323"));
                      }
                      CheckedTextView txt1=(CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
                           txt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#57B7B2"));
                        lastClickedView=txt1;



                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listDataChild.get(
                                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
                });
        }
```

This is one of the activity classes, I have four activity classes like these, please help me.

Comment: So, you need to set different color for 1-st child in each group of listview, right? For this you can use `getChildView` method in your adapter and write something like this .  `if (childPosition == 0) lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); else lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`

Comment: Without selecting any position i want set color for first group position bro...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing colors String in ExpandableListAdapter's constructor but never used it.
If you want to set first group item's color then you need to set it from getGroupView() method of ExpandableListAdapter :
like this:

```
if(groupPosition==0){
lblListHeader.setTextColor(<color passing in constructor>);
}
```

Comment: It works Dani but if i click next position its not changed to balck color

Comment: I am not getting you .
can you please describe the issue briefly ?

Comment: please send me mail i will send pdf images

Comment: nilay.dani@hotmail.com

Comment: Can i know what is the use of  `expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    if(groupPosition==2){
                    lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });`

Comment: Actually group position 2 has child list, That's why I used expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener for showing those child's, And  expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener for hiding child's ,also as per project requirement I used color for that group 2.

Comment: So where is the issue now?